# Datastax Cluster Storage Amazon Ec2 - Production

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I have a Datastax Enterprise cluster in production with the following configuration:

3 Hadoop Nodes
2 Cassandra Nodes
2 Solr Nodes

- There are few tables in Cassandra with few million lines.
- Every night I process few million registers using PIG.
- All the search done in our website uses SOLR.

Basically we are 100% based on DSE.

This structure is based on Amazon Ec2, and all the instances are: 
M3.Xlarge
80 GB SSD
15 GB RAM
13 (4 core x 3.25 unit)

I want to add an extra 1TB Hard Disk for each node and use it in the cluster.
How can I do that? Which config files do I need to change when I attach a new hard disk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After attaching the new hard drive storage to the EC2 instance, edit the `cassandra.yaml` file and add the new storage location to the `data_file_directories` configuration option. (Cassandra supports multiple entries for data storage, and will spread the data out.)

The config file will depend on your installation method, either `/etc/dse/cassandra/cassandra.yaml` or `{install_location}/resources/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml`.

After making the config file change, DSE will need to be restarted on each node (could do a rolling restart).

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23121664/9965

Comment: Thank you a lot for the answer! Quick and easy!